# Is Activity-centered design better than User-Centered design in practice?

Tags: user-behavior, user-centered-design, methodology

A decade ago, Don Norman proposed [Activity-centered design](http://jnd.org/dn.mss/human-centered_design_considered_harmful.html) (ACD) as a better approach compared to Human-cenetered design. I'm curious if anybody here has practised ACD. Did you find it better than HCD/UCD when considering product conversion and usability testing?

I've tried looking at some papers on SIGCHI but none of them give any good details on its practice. It's mostly theoretical in nature.

Comment: This is a slight misunderstanding of the term. Activity-centered design (ACD) is an EXTENSION of the Human-centered design paradigm that focuses on mapping the User’s activities and tasks. They both share the same processes, they just have slightly different focuses.